# Sufficient conditions for the matrix to be invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Consider an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ defined over $\mathbb{F}$ where $1\neq 0$. This matrix is given by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} & \ldots & a_{n-1} & a_{n} \\
  a_{n} & a_{1} & a_{2} &\ldots & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1}\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
  a_{3} & a_{4} & a_{5} & \ldots & a_{1} & a_{2} \\
  a_{2} & a_{3} & a_{4} & \ldots & a_{n} & a_{1}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
For $n=1$, $A$ is invertible if and only if $a_1\neq 0$.

For $n=2$, $A$ is invertible $\Longleftrightarrow\det A=a_1^2-a_2^2\neq0\Longleftrightarrow a_1\neq \pm a_2$.

When $a_2=a_3=\ldots =a_n$, we can calculate $\det A=\left[a_1+(n-1)a_2\right](a_1-a_2)^{n-1}$.Therefore $A$ is invertible if and only if $a_1\neq -(n-1)a_2$ and $a_1\neq a_2$.

If $\mathbb{F}$ is a field with a norm (for example, $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) denoted as $|\cdot|$, we can establish that $A$ is invertible if there exists an integer $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $2|a_i|>\sum^{n}_{j=1}|a_j|$.

However, finding a general condition seems to be quite challenging.

Comment: This is called a circulant matrix and its determinant admits a very explicit and classical factorization into linear factors (over an algebraically closed field) corresponding to its eigenvalues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues $A$ is invertible iff none of these factors are zero.